# Gorilla websocket connections when running multiple instances of the Go application

Tags: go

To save Gorilla websocket connections I could something like this where the key could be a userId.

```
connections := make(map[int]*connection)
```

I am using something called supervisord

http://supervisord.org/

which is a process control system so that I am able to run the go application
in the background as a daemon. It looks like several instances are being spawned up.

[image]

Does those instances know how to access the same connections variable if I make it global?

```
var connections map[int]*connection
```

Or will there be an issue?

Also since map is not thread safe, should I create a struct and add `sync.RWMutex` and do RLock()/Lock() and RUnlock()/Unlock() before checking whether a key exists or when removing a key from the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, those aren't processes but threads, so they will indeed share the same global state. [htop shows threads as if they were processes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10362/why-does-htop-show-more-process-than-ps).

Whenever you need concurrent access to a map, you need to synchronise it. You can indeed do this with a mutex.

Comment: Thanks! What if I do loadbalancing with multiple servers? How would I solve the issue of saving gorilla websocket connections so that all servers would be able to access it?

Comment: @Aiden you'd have to serialise connections. I don't think that's possible. You'd have to rethink your design

Comment: One approach being sticky sessions.